# EU-GDPR and what I need to conciser when developing a CRM hosted on a Virtual Machine

Tags: encryption

I read about the new EU-General Data Protection Regulation and I know nothing about encryption. I am going to host SuiteCRM on a cloud based VM running CentOS7.

In relation to the EU-GDPR do I need to encrypt my entire hard drive? Is this enough? Do I encrypt my database as well? Is this overkill?

A person mentioned a form of encryption in which you enter a key on initalising the device. The key is stored in RAM, and they key is used to encrypt and decrypt all the info that the programs running on the VM use. They didn't mention the name of this technology but knew that I would be using CentOS7. What is this technology and would there be a massive computational overhead in using it? Would this method be sufficient to provide EU-GDPR compliance for the CRM?

Comment: A slight note on the database encryption is that (unless you use some esoteric raw disk mounts for the database itself, or live in 1990 where such mounts made sense), since the database files will be on disk, they will be encrypted anyway.  Encrypting two times does not really provide extra security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should "maintain measures to encrypt personal data" per article 32 Security of processing which states "Integrate data privacy into an information security policy". I would say that this includes in transit and storage level encryption. The tools you can use to achieve this depend on your overall technology stack.

Comment: Thank's! Stack End User> Digital Ocean VM >CentOS7 >Apache Server >SuiteCRM >HTTPS >End  User.